# how to count an element in each index of Arraylist in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, indexing, element

First, I have a string that contain all of characters and then I add it into Arraylist of list1 but I separate it with *. so now I have 5 elements of arraylist.

```
String fString = "DAVCFW_ACK*DAVCFW_20_30_90*DAVCFW_15.5_20.1_35.0*DAVCFW_40_230_110*DAVCFW_END";
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
string[] words = fString.Split('*');
foreach (string s in words)
{
    list1.Add(s);
 }
```

Second, I delete first 6 charecters of each elements and keep it into Arraylist of list2.

```
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
String s1 = list1.ToString();
foreach(string s in list1){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++ ){
         if(i>6){
             list2[i-7] = list1[i];
         }
    }
}
```

Third, I delete all _ characters of each elemeant and keep it into Arraylist of list3. Now I get only number not characters.

```
ArrayList list3 = new ArrayList();
String[] word_s1 = s1.Split('_');
foreach(string s in word_s1){
     list3.Add(s);
}
```

And then I would like to keep the value of list3 like matrix but still is an Arraylist. I need to know number of element in each index of list3 to define row and colomn. For column I think I can use list3.count; but for row I don't know how. After I know row. I have to put 0 to element in each index that have number of row less than row.

Pleas Help me. Thanks you.

Comment: What kind of matrix? Is `List<List<string>>` good for you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever run this code? First of all it doesn't work, because in second listing you are trying to get `list1[7]`, where last index is 5. Second, in the same listing you are accesing element in subloop, not characters. Third, why did you do that `String s1 = list1.ToString()`? `s1` is equal to string `"System.Collections.ArrayList"`.

Back to your question. If you want to get length of every row, just use `string.Length` property. Here is working code:

```
String fString = "DAVCFW_ACK*DAVCFW_20_30_90*DAVCFW_15.5_20.1_35.0*DAVCFW_40_230_110*DAVCFW_END";
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
string[] words = fString.Split('*');
foreach (string s in words)
{
    list1.Add(s);
}

ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
foreach(string s in list1)
{
    list2.Add(s.Substring(6));
}

ArrayList list3 = new ArrayList();
foreach (string s in list2)
{
    list3.Add(s.Replace("_", string.Empty));
}

foreach (string s in list3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Console.WriteLine("Number of rows: {0}", list3.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < list3.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of characters in {0} row: {1}",i, (list3[i] as string).Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. And how about the column? :D

Comment: Wait, now I don't understand you question :) your rows are elements in `list3`, so `list3.Count` gives you number of rows. Every single element in List is your single row. Because they are strings you can get "column count" by accesing `Length` property. And you can manipulate with characters, so you can write logic to "put 0 to element in each index that have number of row less than row".
If you want to have explicit column and rows, I would suggest using `List<List<char>>`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear about what you want. If you are after a matrix of item position as column, and values as rows, you can try something like this.

```
String fString = "DAVCFW_ACK*DAVCFW_20_30_90*DAVCFW_15.5_20.1_35.0*DAVCFW_40_230_110*DAVCFW_END";

Dictionary<int, ArrayList> matrix = new Dictionary<int,ArrayList>();
string[] words = fString.Split('*');
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 2 ; i++) // exclude the first and the last words because they do not have number
{
     string[] numbers = words[i+1].Substring(6).Split('_');
     ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
     for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++) // exlcude the first number as it is empty string
     {
         list.Add(numbers[j]);
     }
     matrix[i] = list;
}
```